# How to save Textlocal's sent otp in database php?

Tags: php, one-time-password

I am creating an OTP system in which I am gathering some info from my customer and in which he will also put his number and when he will click the submit button then an OTP will be sent to him. Now i want to save that OTP in database for further use. I am using text Local for sending OTP this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Send SMS from PHP using textlocal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center">Sending OTP SMS </h1>
<hr>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['sendopt'])) {
                require('textlocal.class.php');
                require('credential.php');

                $textlocal = new Textlocal(false, false, API_KEY);

                // You can access  from credential.php
                // $numbers = array(MOBILE);
                // Access enter mobile number in input box
                $numbers = array($_POST['mobile']);

                $sender = 'TXTLCL';
                $otp = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
                $message = "Hello " . $_POST['uname'] . " This is your OTP: " . $otp;

                try {
                    $result = $textlocal->sendSms($numbers, $message, $sender);
                    setcookie('otp', $otp);
                    echo "OTP successfully send..";
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
            }

            if(isset($_POST['verifyotp'])) { 
                $otp = $_POST['otp'];
                if($_COOKIE['otp'] == $otp) {
                    echo "Congratulation, Your mobile is verified.";
                } else {
                    echo "Please enter correct otp.";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">
        <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
                    <label for="uname">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" value="" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter your name" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
                    <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter valid mobile number" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="sendopt" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Send OTP</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do this any kind of  help would be appreciated.